# linux + RAID - on which disk are my file?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid

I have a server with 4 physical disks ( HP WK 8600).
Seems like the 4 disks are mounted on a RAID card. The Ubuntu 14.04 sees only one disk.

```
-wks:/dev$ lsscsi -g
[2:2:0:0]    disk    INTEL    SRCSAS18E        1.12  /dev/sda   /dev/sg0 
[3:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  TSSTcorp CDDVDW SH-224DB  SB00  /dev/sr0   /dev/sg1

/dev$ sudo parted -l
Model: INTEL SRCSAS18E (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1797GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  1767GB  1767GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      1767GB  1797GB  30,1GB  extended
 5      1767GB  1797GB  30,1GB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

I am not used to the cable branching of servers. The disks are connected with two cables : 1 black, 1 blue (the black is slightly larger than the blue one). I have the feeling that the black cable is connected to the motherboard, while the blue one is connected to a RAID-card. The black cables have number : 'P14 / P 13 / P12 / P11'.

I want to replace one physical disk by a new one I bought. 
The questions are :

1) how to know on which disk is the OS ? So that I don't remove this disk.

2) how to move all the data from the disk I will remove to the other disks ?

3) how to know the link between the physical disks and any "/dev/sdx"-kind of output any software will give me ?

4) which command to use, or which software ?

5) what steps to follow ?

I have been having to the 'How Linux works' book  from Brian Ward (no starch press) - but had no luck to find answers to my precise situation.
Any advice welcome.

EDIT
This thread is the continuation of another conversation : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32101431/linux-raid-on-which-disk-are-my-file?noredirect=1#comment52098255_32101431

The last comment I gave is the following :

So, I added the drive, but it is now the first one to be recognized at boot time, and as it is empy (the OS is certainly on the drive), nothing happen : just a black screen with a blinking underscore on the top left of the screen...

Comment: Please provide a photo as well as the exact specs of the drives your system has. This workstation has no default disk configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** 
I guess that this depends on the RAID level you are using. So you should find out which RAID level your system is set up with. I do not know how to access it the right way, but there might be an option when booting your system. Perhaps there is another way for servers to not have to reboot the machine.

**2)-5)**
Also depending on the RAID level and the controller; there could be some kind of hot-swap mechanism. Perhaps the documentation/manual for the RAID controller might be a way to start.
If I read it correctly, this should be it: http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/server/srcsas18e

Comment: I'd strongly, strongly recommend backing up the system before attempting this, too.